# Why Android is crashing on its own? What have I done wrongly?

Tags: java, android, android-xml, callstack

I am writing an Android app for little kids to learn maths and I am working on the part where users can get prizes when he/she answers all the questions correctly. And I am dynamically adding some views to the right side of the screen to tell the user that he/she has got a prize. (Every possible question option has a corresponding prize!) The left side is used to show the score. However, the app crashed. I tried to look at the call stack to see where did I do wrong. But none of my methods are on the call stack!

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1034)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2196)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16030)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1915)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1290)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1009)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5508)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

See? My package name is called `com.smartkidslovemaths` but it is not one the call stack! How am I supposed to know where I did wrong?

Anyway, I think some of my code are relevant. This is the layout of the right side of the screen:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_side"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is how I add the views, note that this method is called in the `onCreate` method.

```
private void displayPrize () {
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.right_side)).setLayoutParams (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    TextView text = new TextView (this);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 1F
            );

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 8F
            );
    text.setLayoutParams (textParams);
    Resources res = getResources ();
    QuestionOptions options = QuestionsActivity.Options.getOptions ();

    switch (options.getDigitCount ()) {
        case 1:
        default:
            text.setText (res.getText (R.string.earn_star_text));
            break;
        case 2:
            text.setText (res.getText (R.string.earn_badge_text));
            break;
        case 3:
            text.setText (res.getText (R.string.earn_trophy_text));
            break;
    }

    text.setTextSize (res.getDimension (R.dimen.answer_text_size) / 4);

    ((LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.right_side)).addView (text);

    ImageView image = new ImageView (this);
    image.setLayoutParams (imageParams);
    int resID = QuestionOptionMaps.getOptionsDrawableMap ().get (options);
    image.setImageResource (resID);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.right_side)).addView (image);
}
```

I really don't know where I did wrong. Or maybe I am correct and it's just an Android bug?

Comment: It's a ClassCastException. Somewhere, it's trying to cast a type A to an (unrelated) type B.

Comment: But it happened at the internal workings of android. How am I supposed to fix that? @Stultuske

Comment: What is your rationale to cast those `findViewById` calls to a `LinearLayout`?  Android is telling you that's not possible to do, since the classes don't relate at runtime.

Comment: @Makoto If that's what I did wrong, the call stack would say it, right? And also, the view that I am finding _is_ a `LinearLayout`!

Comment: Not every exception has a call stack into your code - and you shouldn't expect it to. A simple example are invalid xml layouts which are inflated by the system - since you don't inflate them yourself, the exception callstack won't show any of your code. It's perfectly normal and not a bug in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScrollView` extends `FrameLayout`.

When set a view's layoutparams you're setting params for the layout they're inside. Therefore in this part:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.right_side)).setLayoutParams(
  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

try replace `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams` with

```
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(...)
```

Comment: But the call stack would tell me this, right? Is this a bug in android?

Comment: It is telling you that. LinearLayout$LayoutParams can't be casted to FrameLayout$LayoutParams. The code that tries to do the casting is in FrameLayout,not in your own code, and it's triggered by a measure or draw pass not by your own code, therefore your code isn't in the trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Change `FrameLayout`s to `LinearLayout`

Comment: why didn't you change `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` in your code?